# If I disable Agents in Azure pipelines, would Azure still charge me for parallel pipelines set in billing?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cost-calculation

I purchased 5 parallel pipelines but after the purchase, I go to the Agent Pools section and disabled 2 Agents. Not sure if Azure will still be charging me for 5 pipelines or just 3 enabled Agents. Can anyone confirm?

[image: No. of parallel jobs]

[image: Disabled Agents]

Not sure if I need to reduce the number of parallel jobs in billing to 3 or I will be billed just for 3 active Agents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jessehouwing is right. You will be charged for the parallel job based on the days you used it during the billing cycle. You could arrange your `Paid Parallel jobs` number in billing page dynamically based on your daily workload.

According to this document for [Purchasing Parallel Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted), you will be charged by `Paid jobs` number in pic below. Disabling the agent machine from agent pool could not stop it from being charged. `When you disable the agent`, you are just prevent the parallel job from being used, the only method to stop being charged for parallel job is cutting off the `Paid parallel jobs` in billing page.

[image]

If you have concern on the expense of parallel jobs. You could check the [Service Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) for your parallel jobs allocation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will be charged for the number of agents even when they are set to disabled.  You need to change the number of agents in the billing section.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/_settings/billing
```

You will be charged to the end of the billing cycle if you lower the number.

Comment: Then what is the use of disabling the Agents?

Comment: Hosted agents, not so much. For self-hosted agents you can bring an agent offline to install things on it or to do other maintenance. Or when an agent is misbehaving and you want to investigate issues.